# Three implementations of mergesort in F#

Tags: sorting, comparative-review, f#, mergesort

I would appreciate some quick comments on this basic mergesort code.
Am I missing a big block in the langage?

### First solution

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Collections.Generic

let shuffle (l:'a array) = 
   let ileft = LinkedList<int>(seq { 0 .. (l.Length - 1)})
   let rec pick (ar:'a array)  r = 
      match ileft.Count with | 0 -> r
                             | n -> let ik =   ileft |> Seq.nth (rnd.Next(n))
                                    ileft.Remove(ik) |> ignore
                                    pick ar (ar.[ik]::r)
   pick l  []

let rec merge (ar1:'a array) (ar2:'a array)  = 
   let rec index (islastfromAr1, ilast, jlast) = seq {
      let inext, jnext = ilast + 1, jlast + 1 
      match inext < ar1.Length, jnext < ar2.Length with
      | true , true  -> let indexnext = if ar1.[inext] < ar2.[jnext] then
                                            (true, inext, jlast)
                                        else
                                            (false, ilast, jnext)
                        yield  Some(indexnext)
                        yield! index indexnext 
      | false, true  -> let indexnext = (false, ilast, jnext)
                        yield  Some(indexnext)
                        yield! index indexnext 
      | true , false -> let indexnext = (true, inext, jlast)
                        yield  Some(indexnext)
                        yield! index indexnext 
      | false, false -> yield  None
   }
   let mergeindex = index (false, -1, -1)
   [for (formar1, i,j) in  mergeindex |> Seq.choose (id) -> if formar1 then ar1.[i] else ar2.[j] ]

and mergesort  = function 
   | [| |]    -> [||]
   | [|a|]    -> [|a|]
   | ar       -> let ar1 = ar.[0 .. ar.Length / 2 - 1]
                 let ar2 = ar.[ar.Length / 2 .. ar.Length - 1]
                 merge (mergesort ar1) (mergesort ar2)  |> List.toArray
let testval = ( [|1 .. 100|] |> shuffle |> List.toArray)                 
let test4 = mergesort testval
```

### Second solution

a shorter, mutable state version of it

```
let rec mergemutable (ar1:'a array) (ar2:'a array)  = 
   let inext, jnext = ref 0 , ref 0

   [ for k in [1 .. (ar1.Length + ar2.Length)]  ->
      match !inext < ar1.Length, !jnext < ar2.Length with
      | true , true  -> if ar1.[!inext] < ar2.[!jnext] then
                           inext := !inext + 1
                           ar1.[!inext - 1]
                        else
                           jnext := !jnext + 1
                           ar2.[!jnext - 1]
      | false, true  -> jnext := !jnext + 1
                        ar2.[!jnext - 1]
      | true , false -> inext := !inext + 1
                        ar1.[!inext - 1 ]
      | _ -> failwith "should not happen"
    ]
and mergesortmutable  = function 
   | [| |]    -> [||]
   | [|a|]    -> [|a|]
   | ar       -> let ar1 = ar.[0 .. ar.Length / 2 - 1]
                 let ar2 = ar.[ar.Length / 2 .. ar.Length - 1]
                 (mergemutable (mergesortmutable ar1) (mergesortmutable ar2) )    |> List.toArray
let testmutable = mergesortmutable   ( [|1 .. 100|] |> shuffle |> List.toArray)
```

It is much faster.

### Third solution

Another one with no extraneous allocations

```
let mergesortmutable2 ar =
   let mutable sarlast = ref (Array.copy ar)
   let mutable sarcurr = ref (Array.copy ar)

   let rec mergemutable (sarcurr:'a array ref) (sarlast:'a array ref) s (s1,e1) (s2,e2)  = 
      let mutable inext, jnext = s1 , s2

      for k in [1 ..  ((e1-s1+1) + (e2-s2+1)) ] do
         match inext <= e1, jnext <= e2 with
         | true , true  -> if (!sarlast).[inext] < (!sarlast).[jnext] then
                              (!sarcurr).[(s+(k-1))] <- (!sarlast).[inext]
                              inext <- inext + 1
                           else
                              (!sarcurr).[(s+(k-1))] <- (!sarlast).[jnext]
                              jnext <- jnext + 1
         | false, true  -> (!sarcurr).[(s+(k-1))] <- (!sarlast).[jnext]
                           jnext <- jnext + 1
         | true , false -> (!sarcurr).[(s+(k-1))] <- (!sarlast).[inext]
                           inext <- inext + 1
         | _ -> failwith "should not happen"
      (s1,e2)
   and mergesortmutable (sarcurr:'a array ref) (sarlast:'a array ref) (s,e) = 
      match s, e with
       | s, e when s >= e -> s,e
       | _                -> let m = (e-s+1) / 2
                             let ar1 = (mergesortmutable sarlast sarcurr (s, s + m - 1))
                             let ar2 = (mergesortmutable sarlast sarcurr (s + m, e))
                             let ret = mergemutable sarcurr sarlast s ar1 ar2
                             ret
   do mergesortmutable  sarcurr sarlast (0, ar.Length - 1) |> ignore
   !sarcurr
```

Comment: I'd put the code that does the split in a separate function. Though something about your merge code rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: i also wonder if that is not the kind of stuff where one should use mutable variable.

Comment: the array being a ref type already, no need to enclose it in a ref

Comment: Have you googled "f# merge sort"? [Here](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/03/test.html) is a particularly good one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just learning F# myself, but here is what I currently notice:

1. Your `merge` function is very large.  It should be split into multiple small functions that are responsible for a single action.
2. `match` is preferred to `if`:

> ```
> if ar1.[inext] < ar2.[jnext] then
>     (true, inext, jlast)
> else
>     (false, ilast, jnext)
> ```

can be written as:

```
match ar1.[inext] with
| i when i < ar2.[jnext] -> (true, inext, jlast)
| _ -> (false, ilast, jnext)
```

3. `islastfromAr1` is never used.  This parameter can probably be removed.